# how to separate and sort numbers in python?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

Given a variable containing integer numbers with the provisions of the number 0 (zero) in the variable is a separator between one number with another number. The numbers will be separated and ordered by the numbers in the numbers themselves. After that, the numbers from the sort will be rejoined without separating with the output in the form of integer numbers. Make a method / function that accepts parameters only a series of numbers and produces output like the description above.

```py
def sort(nums):
    for i in range (15):
        minpos = 1
        for j in range (i,6):
            if nums[j] < nums[minpos]:
                minpos = j

        temp = nums[i]
        nums[i] = nums[minpos]
        nums[minpos] = temp

nums = [5,9,5,6,5,6,0,1,5,9,4,6,6,0,5,6]
sort(nums)

print(nums)
```

The output should be 55566914566956 , but actual output is [5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 9, 0, 1, 5, 9, 4, 6, 6, 0, 6]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following function:

```
def sort(nums):
    curr = []
    ret = ''
    for i in nums:
        if i == 0:
            ret += ''.join(map(str, sorted(curr)))
            curr = []
        else:
            curr.append(i)
    ret += ''.join(map(str, sorted(curr)))
    return ret

print(sort([5,9,5,6,5,6,0,1,5,9,4,6,6,0,5,6]))
```

Prints:

```
55566914566956
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort(nums):
  result = list()
  sub_array = list()
  for i in nums:
    if i == 0:
      # sort sub array and append it to result
      sub_array.sort()
      result.extend(sub_array)
      sub_array = list()
    else:
        sub_array.append(i)

  # ensure that the last sub_array is also treated 
  sub_array.sort()
  result.extend(sub_array)

  return result

nums = [5,9,5,6,5,6,0,1,5,9,4,6,6,0,5,6]
result = sort(nums)

print(result)
```

The easiest way is to loop through your list and create a sub array of numbers up until you find a '0'. At this point, simply order your sub array, append it to your result list and continue until the end of your input string.